# How do I find the minimal polynomial for 11th roots of unity sum $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$. Non-trivial seemingly

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive 11th root of unity, how does one show that $\alpha= \zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ has minimal polynomial $x^5+x^4-4x^3-3x^2+3x+1$?

I have been unable to solve this problem that I would have assumed was simple for hours... It gives a hint that we can evaluate the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ at $\zeta$ and divide each side by $\zeta^5$, and rewrite in terms of $\alpha$, but I can't get it:

$$\zeta=z\text{ for saving type it 200 times}$$
$$z^{10}+z^9+\cdots+z+1=0$$
$$z^5+z^4+\cdots+z^{-4}+z^{-5}=0$$
$$z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+1+z^{-2}+z^{-3}+z^{-4}+z^{-5}+\alpha=0$$
$$$$

How is this meant to give me the minimal polynomial?

Comment: $$\alpha^2=z^2+2+z^{-2}$$
$$\alpha^3=z^3+3z+3z^{-1}+z^{-3}$$
$$\alpha^4=z^4+4z^2+6+z^{-2}+z^{-4}$$
$$\alpha^5=z^5+5z^3+10z+10z^{-1}+5z^{-3}+z^{-5}$$
Exploit the symmetry in the coefficients of powers with negative exponents...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how much Galois theory you know. I would do it as follows, which is not so easily seen to be related to the hint you were given. The Galois group of the splitting field of $x^{11}-1$ is cyclic of order $10$, and is generated by $\sigma: \sigma(\zeta) = \overline{\zeta}$ and $\tau : \tau(\zeta) = \zeta^{4}$. The element $\alpha$ is already fixed by $\sigma$. Now $\tau^{5}$ is the identity,
and it follows that the coefficients of the polynomial
$(x - \alpha)(x - \tau(\alpha))(x-\tau^{2}(\alpha))(x-\tau^{3}(\alpha))(x- \tau^{4}(\alpha))$ are fixed by both $\sigma$ and $\tau$, so are fixed by the full Galois group, and lie in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Hence if you expand out $(x - (\zeta+\zeta^{-1}))(x - (\zeta^{4}+\zeta^{-4}))(x - (\zeta^{5}+\zeta^{-5}))(x - (\zeta^{2}+\zeta^{-2}))(x - (\zeta^{3}+\zeta^{-3}))$, you will obtain a polynomial of degree $5$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ satisfied by $\alpha$, and it is easy to check that this has to be the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$. By the way, I have made use of the fact that $\zeta^{11}= 1$, so that $\zeta^{16} = \zeta^{5}$ and $\zeta^{20} = \zeta^{9} = \zeta^{-2}$. Likewise $\zeta^{8} = \zeta^{-3}$.

Comment: Are you missing the factor $(x-(\zeta^3 + \zeta^{-3}))$?(otherwise it only be of degree 5?)

Comment: Yes, sorry indeed I am- fixed

Comment: I think I am missing something still :S, the computation of the above:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-%28z%2Bz%5E%28-1%29%29%29%28x-%28z%5E4%2Bz%5E%28-4%29%29%29%28x-%28z%5E5%2Bz%5E%28-5%29%29%29%28x-%28z%5E2%2Bz%5E%28-2%29%29%29%28x-%28z%5E3%2Bz%5E%28-3%29%29%29%2C+z%5En+%3D+z%5E%28n+mod+11%29

yields $(x-2)^5 = x^5-10x^4+40x^3-80x^2+80x-32$

Comment: But $\alpha \neq 2$, so I do not know what you or wolfram are doing-maybe using the wrong $11$-th root of unity for $\zeta$. You can do it by hand with a little work.

Comment: Yeah I guess wolfram doesn't work for some reason, but I don't know how else to verify(by hand would take hours haha)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is not $x^{11}-1$, which has $1$ as a root, but instead $$\dfrac{x^{11}-1}{x-1} = x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1.$$

Comment: why isn't $x^{11}=1$ the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$?

Comment: Minimum polynomials are always irreducible, and $x^{11}-1$ has a factor $x-1$.

Comment: Oh my god... I'm an idiot... @GeoffRobinson thanks

Comment: You're being a little harsh on yourself.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I spent hours haha, it's alright though, hopefully I can find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ now

Comment: Oh I just realised my title choice was bad, but the question body was what I wanted just to be sure